# Flutter - A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, widget

I am having an error as regards fetching data from firestore using futureBuilder. When I do a print of snapshot.data without calling a Text widget, I get an instance of 'User'.

Without Calling author.fullname

```
body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: _posts.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      Post post = _posts[index];
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: DatabaseService.getUserWithId(post.authorid),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              User author = snapshot.data;
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[],
              );
            }
          }
          return SizedBox.shrink();
```

**Output**

```
Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 1,146ms.
flutter: Instance of 'User'
flutter: Instance of 'User'
```

However when I try to call for the fullname of the user from firestore, it returns null

```
body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: _posts.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      Post post = _posts[index];
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: DatabaseService.getUserWithId(post.authorid),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              User author = snapshot.data;
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(author.fullname)
                ],
              );
            }
          }
          return SizedBox.shrink();
```

**Output**

```
Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 1,042ms.
flutter: Instance of 'User'
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY   
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<User>(dirty, state:
flutter: _FutureBuilderState<User>#23d74):
flutter: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
flutter: Failed assertion: line 285 pos 10: 'data != null'
flutter:
flutter: Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
flutter: more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
flutter: In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
flutter:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
flutter:
flutter: The relevant error-causing widget was:
flutter:   FutureBuilder<User> file:///Users/momo/Desktop/combine/lib/screens/home.dart:65:18
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #2      new Text (package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart:285:10)
flutter: #3_HomeState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:combine/screens/home.dart:75:23)
flutter: #4      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart)
flutter: #5      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4334:27)
flutter: #6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4223:15)
flutter: #7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
flutter: #8      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2432:33)
flutter: #9      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:773:20)
flutter: #10     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:283:5)
flutter: #11     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
flutter: #12     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1041:9)
flutter: #13     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:957:5)
flutter: #17     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:259:10)
flutter: #18     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:217:3)
flutter: (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async)
```

**User Class**

```
class User {
  final String id;
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String fullname;

User(
    {this.id,
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.fullname,});

factory User.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  return User(
    id: doc.documentID,
    email: doc['email'],
    fullname: doc['fullname'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It appears that the received data is an object instance of the User class please provide it's code if you have no problem.

Comment: @Sparks I have edited it to include the User class

Comment: You have onlt one Text Widget i.e. Text(author.fullname) so most probably author.fullname is null. use print(author.fullname); to verify it in build method. Try Text(author.fullname==null?'--':author.fullname)

Comment: @Dev Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 1,248ms.
flutter: Instance of 'User'
flutter: null
flutter: Instance of 'User'
flutter: null

Comment: what does print ( snapshot.data.fullname ) gives you in the console?

Comment: @Sparks flutter: null flutter:null. So i think it's not calling the Class value

Comment: You are using "Future" so try to make the builder method as async and make the code to wait for result first like I will post down

Comment: Did you try to put <User> as a generic type for AsyncSnapshot as: AsyncSnapshot<User>? since there is no reason for it to give an error

Answer (score 1):

You must provide an empty text in case the name is null

```
return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(author.fullname == null? '' : author.fullname)
                ],
              );
```

Comment: flutter: null flutter:null.